# What is the best way for me to share bool values between my computer and my android phone using python?

Tags: python, android, kivy

For my project I am trying to have my Android phone take pictures of lights that are powered by my computer.  I am doing this through an app I am building with Kivy.  What I need to do is to for multiple lights is the following:

Android: Ask for light (x) to be turned on
Computer: Turn light (x) on
Android: Take photo and tell computer photo has been taken
Computer: Turn light (x) off
...

If I were to do this all on one computer I would make the status of the light a bool value (ex. lightOn == True) and would just check if it is True of False.

What is the best way for me to share the status of the light between my computer and my android phone?

Comment: Using Firebase Cloud Messaging will help you.. You can observe if your value inside JSON change

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is to use sockets, create a socket connection between the computer and your android device and then change the boolean values on given command passed through the socket connection [socket tutorial](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/socket-programming/).
one other solution *not very optimal* is to use an API the values will be set by the android application and the requests will be made from the computer, for this case I recommend flask-restful, it's really an easy way to create the API you'll need, [flask-restful docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)